# Cómo puedo ejecutar de manera consecutiva varios AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Deseo Ejecutar varios `AsyncTask` en Android  de manera ordenada 1, 2, 3, 4. Uno detrás de otro. Se me ocurre colocar uno en cada `success` del anterior, ¿esto sería lo más correcto? ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Los AsyncTask son asincronos. Sera que lo quieres es es ejecutarlos que se ejecuten uno detras de otro? Que cuando termine uno, comienze el otro?

Comment: no me explique bien ha eso me refiere uno detras de otros como lo podria hacer, se me ocurre colocar uno en cada success del anterior. esto seria lo mas correcto?

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es siempre que termine el task en el metodo `onPostExecute`, ejecutar la siguiente task. Aunque lo mejor seria ejecutarlo todo en el mismo Task ya que al parecer los procesos son dependientes uno del otro si lo necesitas en orden.

Otra cosa que puedes hacer es crear tu propia clase para que ejecute los procesos en orden en caso de lo requieras todos juntos en otro hilo. Por ejemplo con esta clase puedo separar los procesos para organizarlos aunque se ejecuta en el mismo hilo:

```
public class ContinuousTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {


    private Stack<Runnable> runnables = new Stack<>();
    private Runnable onFinish;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        while(!runnables.isEmpty())
        {
            runnables.pop().run();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        if(onFinish != null)
            onFinish.run();
    }

    public ContinuousTask then(Runnable runnable)
    {
        runnables.push(runnable);
        return this;
    }

    public ContinuousTask finish(Runnable runnable)
    {
        onFinish = runnable;
        return this;
    }
}
```

El uso seria asi:

```
new ContinuousTask().then(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              // codigo 1

            }
        }).then(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              // codigo 2

            }
        }).then(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              // codigo 3  
            }
        }).finish(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              // metodo final  
            }
        }).runTasks();// se ejecuta los tasks
```